# jQuery syntax error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I found an example here on stackoverflow that I am trying to recreate and use a solution.
here is the link to the example: [Refreshing Partial View in MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977043/refreshing-partial-view-in-mvc-3)

what is wrong with my syntax?

```
function RefreshPartial() {
        $('#invited-teams').load('/Challenge/GetInvitedTeams', {Model.ChallengeId});
    }
```

will this work?  or does it need to have the curly brackets?

```
function RefreshPartial() {
        $('#invited-teams').load('/Challenge/GetInvitedTeams', "<%= Model.ChallengeId %>" );
    }
```

UPDATE:

```
 function RefreshPartial() {
        $('#invited-teams').load('/Challenge/GetInvitedTeams',
            {'paramname' : <%:Model.ChallengeId %> });
    }
```

my partial view:

```
            <div id="invited-teams">
                <% Html.RenderPartial("InvitedTeams", Model.InvitedTeams); %>
            </div>
```

So, this is what my refreshPartial method is looking like:

```
function RefreshPartial() {
        alert("in refresh partial");
        alert("<%:Model.ChallengeId %>");
        $('#invited-teams').load('/Challenge/GetInvitedTeams', { 
            'paramname': '<%:Model.ChallengeId %>'
        });


    }
```

it alerts both alerts correctly, with the 2nd one having the correct ChallengeID.  The page is still going blank though. hmm..

Comment: What view engine are you using?

Comment: sorry, i am using ASP.NET MVC 3.  the view page is a .aspx file... if that helps

Answer (score 3):

Your function does not specify a parameter name.

```
function RefreshPartial() {
    $('#invited-teams').load('/Challenge/GetInvitedTeams', {
       'paramname' :'<%:Model.ChallengeId %>'//Or your ASP wrapper here
    });
}
```

Comment: so, i wrote this, and it doesnt have syntax errors. i have not run it yet.

Comment: let me try to run it. might take a few minutes.

Comment: Okay... so, it didn't work. What it is doing is it looks like it is going to refresh, and then the whole page goes white.  If i hit refresh the page loads back up fine.  I set a breakpoint in the method and it is not getting hit..

Comment: @user1977591, Do you understand the function of .load()? It loads the content of a page/URL in a specified element. Read [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: I just noticed that dakait added some single quotes. ill try that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understand it.  I have a list of teams that I want to invite to a challenge.  Once they are invited, I hide their link, and then I want to refresh the list of invited teams so that they appear there.  That is why i want to use this .load method. i will place the piece of code for the partial view in my original post. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @user1977591, I just pointed out your syntax error, the logic however is a different part.

Comment: What do you mean?  you don't think I can refresh a partial view?

Comment: @user1977591, No, I mean I do not know How you will code your application further.

Comment: Well i guess it isnt going to go much farther since i cant get this refresh to work. and the method is not getting hit.

Comment: @user1977591, The value of challenge Id gets passed as `paramname`. SO check this param in your application.

Comment: Hey 1977591 i updated my original post. the challengeId is getting passed correctly